# Vectr: How to create a circular arc with rounded edges

Tags: vector, shapes, vectr

I'm trying to make a curved arc with rounded edges using Vectr. I can get it to work with perfectly circular arcs by adding a circle to the end[image: circular arc]

However, when I try with an arc made from an oval, it doesn't come out quite right.
[image: ovoid arc]

Does anyone know how to do this in Vectr (or is Vectr just not up to the task)?

Comment: Usually in vector software, something like that would be done using end caps on strokes. Having never used "Vectr", I've no idea if it's capable of that. Is there a user manual where you could look it up perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of Vectr before, but looking at it for a few moments, and using the online version, there does not appear to be any method to alter end caps of strokes on paths, or alter shapes in any sort of custom manner. It looks, *exceptionally* rudimentary in it's editing capabilities, generally only allowing basic predefined shapes and standard bezier paths. Checking their help section, there's no reference to rounding anywhere or end caps.

You may be better off exploring something like **[InkScape](https://inkscape.org/en/)** (which is free). Inkscape offers *much* more editing capabilities.

Comment: The title, body specify Vectr. https://vectr.com/

Comment: Great, I'll check out InkScape. I'm running into other issues with Vectr anyway...